# Rails Load Partial based on Media Query

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to load a menu bar for `@media (min-width: 768px)` but I would like to remove the menu bar if `@media (min-width: 480px)`.

I thought I could use a conditional but it doesn't work for `css`.

Is there a way to not show a html partial based on the media query?

Comment: When CSS is being parsed, the whole html has already been delivered from server to browser. Rails has no chance to know the result of media query.

Comment: Good point @Aetherus I've submitted an edit and removed the Ruby tags.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this in your CSS

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  #menu-bar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```